# C# -Windows App - Regular Expression Help

Tags: c#

I have a textBox control that lets the user their email address/addresses.
The use may enter email by supplying comma or in next line (new line).

The task is to check whether the textBox contains  **new line (\n)**  character or 
 **commas**  then split the email addresses accordingly.

I applied:


**string[] emails = txtemailAddress.Text.Split('\n');**


it splits the email addresses.

**I need a single routine that should check whether the textBox contains ",' {or} '\n' and
split the string based on the split character.If the   *email address is  invalid in format*  it should throw exception as well.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string.Split method accepts an array of characters to split on:

```
// split on newline or comma
txtemailAddress.Text.Split(new[]{'\n', ','});
```

Regarding validating email addresses, this is one of those tasks that may seem simple at first glance, but that proves to be more of a challange than expected. [This has been dicussed here at SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses).

Answer (score 0):

it's not easy to write a parser to check if email is correct or not. 
for splitting you can pass array of chars to split by using it like

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',', '\n' };
string[] emails = txtemailAddress.Text.Split(delimiters );
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are good, but since you asked about regular expression: **`\s*,\s*|\s+`** should work, I believe. It splits between commas (with any amount of whitespace before or after it) and any form of whitespace (newline, space, tab, etc.).

```
var addresses = Regex.Split(text, @"\s*,\s*|\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

To split use

```
string[] emails = txtemailAddress.Text.Split('\n', ',');
```

this method is faster than regular expressions

To validate email see these questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+email

this is too complicated task to open another discussion here.